# How to get Nsuserdefault value in same ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I want to make simple application in which patient can select data of appointment.

I use button to display each data after clicking on button.the button will disable so user can not select same button multiple time. I'm going to store the tag(My tag represent DATA from 1 to 31) of button in array then this array is stored in `NSUserDefaults`.
Now my problem is that when next time user come all button was enabled but I want to disable those button which are already selected

When user click on button following method will called

```
-(void)AddAppointment :(UIButton *)sender
 {

     int DATA=(int)sender.tag; 

     //add data in array
     [arrayApp addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:DATA]];
     NSLog(@"AppointmentFixed=%@",arrayApp);
     UIButton *btnTemp=(UIButton *)[scrlView viewWithTag:DATA];
     btnTemp.enabled=false;

     [btnTemp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

     //add array in nsuserdefault  
     userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [userDefault setObject:arrayApp forKey:@"data"];
 }
```

I use following code to disable those button which are already selected when next time user come

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arrayApp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 

  //get the array from nsuserdefault (not working )
    arrayTemp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    arrayTemp=   [userDefault objectForKey:@"data"];
  //ArrayTemp doenst get any array it is just null :(

    for (int i=0; i<=arrayTemp.count; i++)
    {
        UIButton *btn2=(UIButton *)[scrlView viewWithTag:[[arrayTemp objectAtIndex:i+1] integerValue]];
        btn2.enabled=YES;
        [btn2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code seems right, for setting array in `NSUserDefaults` and getting array from `NSUserDefaults`.

only mistake i see is `key` you are using for setting and getting value to and from `NSUserDefaults` are different.

you are using key "date" while setting array to UserDefaults and key "data" while getting from UserDefaults.

also, don't forget to `synchronize` UserDefaults when you do any changes like below,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i make key name same but my problem is still  there

Comment: check the array before storing to userdefaults that it is not nil and debug to find issue@Priya

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that your NSuserDefault key is different while storing and retrieving the array. And you might be just missed first index of array in the Loop

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arrayApp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 

  //get the array from nsuserdefault (not working )
    arrayTemp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    arrayTemp=   [userDefault objectForKey:@"date"];

 //ArrayTemp doenst get any array it is just null :(

    for (int i=0; i<arrayTemp.count; i++)
    {
        UIButton *btn2=(UIButton *)[scrlView viewWithTag:[[arrayTemp objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]];
        btn2.enabled=YES;
        [btn2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];


    }

}
```